# Question about length of commercial augers

Tags: drilling

I am planning on buying a 16mm auger for a project of mine. I was wondering if the length given (such as 460mm) included the shank and tang or if it just specified how long the business end of the auger was?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to engineering. If you have a product in mind, please put the link up. That way some one may read it and interpret it more correctly. As it stands, this question requires too many assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

I have a commercial soil auger. It is 30 mm diameter and 200 mm long plus several extensions about 12 mm diameter. Various diameter wood bit augers are 200 to 400 mm long.